# Using matlab kalman for nonlinear system estimation

Tags: matlab, estimation, kalman-filter, state-space

I have a non-linear system described by a collection of first-order, non-linear difference equations:

```
x(k) = f(x(k-1)) + u(k-1)
y(k) = h(x(k)) + v(k)
```

where `u(k-1)` and `v(k)` are independent, zero-mean Gaussian noise processes with covariances `Q` and `R`, respectively.

I would like to use the `kalman` function in matlab to estimate `x` given `y`. However, the interface in the matlab control system toolbox is:

```
[K,L,P]= kalman(sys, Q, R, N)
```

where `sys` is the state-space model. My question is: how do I define `sys` for my system of first-order, non-linear difference equations in matlab?

Comment: Kalman filter can only be used for linear systems since the theory does not hold for non linear system. If your non linear system is operating around an equilibrium point you can linearize the system at that point and then use Kalman Filter for estimation. You may want to see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter

Comment: I agree. You need to use extended Kalman filter in which `f` and `h` will be linearized around previously estimated state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the `kalman` function is only for linear systems. However, for highly non-linear systems, the extended kalman filter (EKF) may be a poor estimator. In these cases, the *unscented* kalman filter (UKF) may be better. So, you may want to try both.

Matlab code for either (EKF or UKF) may be found in the [EKF/UKF Toolbox for Matlab here](http://becs.aalto.fi/en/research/bayes/ekfukf/). Another UKF implementation that is suited for your additive noise model can be found [at Matlab Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18217-learning-the-unscented-kalman-filter).

Hope this helps.